# vscode: Is it possible to make (not remap) `caps lock` as one of the modifier keys?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am not asking to remap `Caps Lock` to other modifier keys but I want to configure `Caps Lock` as one of modifier key for my own usage. Any ideas? :D

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: @PanJunjie潘俊杰 Yes I am. But suggestions for `os x` or `linux` are also welcomed :D

Answer (score 2):

On Windows you can use [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)(usually briefly as ahk) with the `WinActive` function to make the ahk script only work when you're in vscode, mapping `CapsLock+*` keys to usually-not-used combinations like `ctrl+shift+alt+*` and write the `ctrl+shift+alt+*` keys to vscode's key configs.

It would roughly look like this:

```
; comment: the class used here is made up
; right click a running script in the system tray and go to "window spy" to get the right class name
; there are also usual `if`s but this one applies the condition to all the code following it
#If WinActive("ahk_class VSCode")

CapsLock & a::
SendInput, ^+!a
return
```

And of course if you want to get the function of capslock in the editor, you can easily use a combination like `CapsLock & Shift` to acomplish it like above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I'd prefer to use pure vscode functions rather than dependencies :D

Comment: Is there any way to use a variable on input and make all `CapsLock`+%letter% auto remap to `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Alt`+%letter%?

Comment: Nevermind, I simply looped through alphabet with js.

Answer (score 0):

For x11 OSes like most Linux distros, use `xmodmap`. Something like

```
keycode 66 = Alt_L Meta_L
clear mod1
add mod1 = Alt_L Meta_L
```

in your `.Xmodmap` file should suffice.

Then run:

```
xmodmap .Xmodmap
```